hx trigger : golang, htmx
I have a problem with hx-trigger parameter. I want to fetch a data from /temp and send to output every 2 second (i send a templ component) but it doesn't work for me
request print only once in my case. Data changes only on refresh manually
Output:
<div id="data-div" 
     hx-get="/temp" 
     hx-trigger="load,every 2s" 
     hx-swap="outerHTML"
     >
</div>

func (serv *Server) temp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    if r.Method == http.MethodGet {
        log.Print("request")
        t := []types.Stock{
            types.Stock{
                Name:      "KAVIX",
                Price:     rand.Float64(),
                PricePrev: 2345.234567,
            },
            types.Stock{
                Name:      "RAVIX",
                Price:     rand.Float64(),
                PricePrev: 25345.234567,
            },
            types.Stock{
                Name:      "GAVIX",
                Price:     rand.Float64(),
                PricePrev: 25.234567,
            },
        }

        err := Render(w, r, components.Stock(t))
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    return nil
}

I also use own  JavaScript trigger function but it also didn't work


Make sure your backend returns an actual response (is not there hanging.. or smth)
Check for any js errors in the console, which may cause the htmx to stop working properly.

